# How to validate JWT Bearer Token in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: azure, .net-core, jwt, token

I have developed a front-end application that manages to get a jwt token from Azure AD.

I manage to put this token in the headers and send the request to my back-end.

I checked the token with online tools, it is valid.

On URL that do not need token I can get it and decode it.

But when I notice an URL as [Authorize] I still get answers 401, and I do not see how to do so that my back-end can validate my token.

I have no idea what to put in the Startup.cs of my .NET Core 2.2 project

Does anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Have you checked my article on the topic: https://joonasw.net/view/azure-AD-authentication-aspnet-core-api-part-1?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution :

In appsettings.json :

```
"AzureActiveDirectory": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "<Domain>",
    "TenantId": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TenantId>/v2.0",
    "ClientId": "<ClientId>"
  }
```

In Startup.cs :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme).AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureActiveDirectory", options));
services.AddAuthorization(o =>
{
    o.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
        .Build();
});
```